# How can I get this query to return 0 instead of null?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT (SUM(tblTransaction.AmountPaid) - SUM(tblTransaction.AmountCharged)) AS TenantBalance, tblTransaction.TenantID
    FROM tblTransaction
    GROUP BY tblTransaction.TenantID
```

But there's a problem with it; there are other TenantID's that don't have transactions and I want to get those too.

For example, the transaction table has 3 rows for bob, 2 row for john and none for jane. I want it to return the sum for bob and john AND return 0 for jane. (or possibly null if there's no other way)

How can I do this?

Tables are like this:

```
Tenants  
  ID  
  Other Data  
Transactions  
  ID  
  TenantID (fk to Tenants)
  Other Data
```

Comment: Rewrote the query in my answer, I misunderstood exactly what you were asking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(You didn't state your sql engine, so I'm going to link to the MySQL documentation).

This is pretty much exactly what the [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function is meant for. You can feed it a list, and it'll return the first non-null value in the list. You would use this in your query as follows:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SUM(tr.AmountPaid) - SUM(tr.AmountCharged)), 0) AS TenantBalance, te.ID
FROM tblTenant AS te
    LEFT JOIN tblTransaction AS tr ON (tr.TenantID = te.ID)
GROUP BY te.ID;
```

That way, if the `SUM()` result would be NULL, it's replaced with zero.

**Edited**: I rewrote the query using a LEFT JOIN as well as the `COALESCE()`, I think this is the key of what you were missing originally. If you only select from the Transactions table, there is no way to get information about things **not** in the table. However, by using a left join from the Tenants table, you should get a row for every existing tenant.

Comment: I don't know if this works because I found my own solution, but I'm assuming it will and the community seems to like it so I'm selecting it as the answer.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work, it returns the same results as my previous query. (i.e., it doesn't return null or 0 values)

Comment: Let me rewrite the query then, I think I see the problem.

Comment: You had a field name off but I fixed it for you. It works, and it returns 0 instead of null, thank you!

Comment: Worked for me in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm nostalgic for last time I used COALESCE: 2001

Answer (score 1):

Below is a full walkthrough of the problem. The function isnull has also been included to ensure that a balance of zero (rather than null) is returned for Tenants with no transactions.

```
create table tblTenant
(
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    Name varchar(100)
);

create table tblTransaction
(
    ID  int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    tblTenantID int,
    AmountPaid  money,
    AmountCharged money
);

insert into tblTenant(Name)
select 'bob' union all select 'Jane' union all select 'john';

insert into tblTransaction(tblTenantID,AmountPaid, AmountCharged)
select 1,5.00,10.00
union all
select 1,10.00,10.00
union all
select 1,10.00,10.00
union all
select 2,10.00,15.00
union all 
select 2,15.00,15.00


select * from tblTenant
select * from tblTransaction

SELECT 
    tenant.ID, 
    tenant.Name,
    isnull(SUM(Trans.AmountPaid) - SUM(Trans.AmountCharged),0) AS Balance 
FROM tblTenant tenant
    LEFT JOIN tblTransaction Trans ON 
        tenant.ID = Trans.tblTenantID
GROUP BY tenant.ID, tenant.Name;

drop table tblTenant;
drop table tblTransaction;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Tenants.ID, ISNULL((SUM(tblTransaction.AmountPaid) - SUM(tblTransaction.AmountCharged)), 0) AS TenantBalance
From Tenants 
Left Outer Join Transactions Tenants.ID = Transactions.TenantID
Group By Tenents.ID
```

I didn't syntax check it but it is close enough.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Tenents.ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "tblTransaction.AmountPaid" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "tblTransaction.AmountCharged" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SUM(ISNULL(tblTransaction.AmountPaid, 0)) 
        - SUM(ISNULL(tblTransaction.AmountCharged, 0))) AS TenantBalance
       , tblTransaction.TenantID
        FROM tblTransaction
        GROUP BY tblTransaction.TenantID
```

I only added this because if you're intention is to take into account for one of the parts being null you'll need to do the ISNULL separately

Comment: only returns the tenants that have transactions.

Comment: @Malfist you're original question does not include an account for what you call tenants, where's the join on the tenants that you're saying is related?

Comment: The question does list the table structure, along with the FK to the tenant table.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I found an answer:

```
SELECT tenant.ID, ISNULL(SUM(trans.AmountPaid) - SUM(trans.AmountCharged),0) AS Balance FROM tblTenant tenant
LEFT JOIN tblTransaction trans
ON tenant.ID = trans.TenantID
GROUP BY tenant.ID
```

Comment: Yes, I said null or 0 but I preferred 0. That's why this isn't selected as the answer.